# How to show only the first ul level and not the second ul level(within the same div) using jquery selection

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $nav = $('#nav');
    var $items = $nav;
    console.log($items.text());
  });
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="selected"><a href="http://docs.jquery.com">jQuery Docs</a></li>
   <li><a href="sandbox.html">Sandbox</a></li>
   <li>Resources
    <ul>
     <li><a href="http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en">Google Group</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://delicious.com/rdmey/jquery-class">Delicious Bookmarks</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

I would like to somehow display only the first level of ul (jQuery Docs,Sandbox and Resources) without displaying any child elements of Resources. How can I accomplish this using jquery selectotion.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Couple way you can approach this:

**Jquery Solution:**

```
$(function(){
     $("#nav > li").show();
     $("#nav li > ul").hide();
});
```

**CSS Solution**

```
#nav > li {display:block;}
#nav li > ul{display:none;}
```

**Update**

```
$(function(){
 var items = [];
 $("#nav > li").each(function(){
    items.push($(this.text());
 });
 console.log(items);
});
```

Comment: How can I ONLY show first level of ul on the console using jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean on the console?

Comment: I would like to show these three items of the first level of the ul using the console. So for an example: lets say the three items are stored in a variable $var item, I would use that variable to display it on the console like this: console.log($item.text());

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css rules:

```
ul li ul{display: none}
```

Comment: It should be "ul li  > ul" . This will select only directly nested lists. Also, you should specify an ID  or this will affect all lists.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer is correct, but I wanted to point out one thing. When you have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $nav = $('#nav');
    var $items = $nav;
    console.log($items.text());
});
```

You're setting two different variables, $nav and $items, to the JQuery object $('#nav'). That's ok, if you want to perform some operation on them, but if you're looking to display the text of your list, you'll need to do Mark's answer.

Comment: I just tried Marks answer and it gives me only JQuery Docs,Sandbox but I am missing Resources (without its children).How can I modify the code in order to see Resources as well.

Comment: Where are you missing it? In the console? On the page?

Comment: In the console is shows only JQuery Docs and Sandbox. Resource is missing.

Comment: It's a little convoluted, but if you're really desperate to have the console respond with all of them, do something like giving each <li> element an id equal to what you want to show. ei: <li id="resources">Resources</li>. Then change your JQuery to read: items.push($(this).id).